# Maximum How many Stars we can add in pointer variable

Tags: c++, c

When programming in c++, how many pointer level we can use?

I am trying to use a two level pointer indirection.

Comment: There is no limit. See [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: More than you should ever need.

Comment: Even sky is not the limit.

Comment: Long ago, with COM/OLE, nearly everyone was a 4-star programmer once you'd passed an `IUnknown****` around.

Comment: @angew which answer in the linked "duplicate" question answers the above question for C++?  I read them all, and did not find it.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ (Document Number: N3797 Date: 2013-10-13) the recommended minimum for implementations is the following

> — Pointer, array, and function declarators (in any combination)
>   modifying a class, arithmetic, or incomplete type in a declaration
>   [256].

in C (N1548 Committee Draft — December 2, 2010)

> — 12 pointer, array, and function declarators (in any combinations)
>   modifying an arithmetic, structure, union, or void type in a
>   declaration

Comment: That is the recommended limit for what the compiler itself should support.  It is not in any way, shape or form the recommended limit for programmers writing code.  ;)

Comment: Good answer, but a cite for the relevant standards would make it better.

Comment: @John Hascall I have added references.